# pygame alpha mask to make objects "invisible"

Tags: python, box2d

I have the points of a polygon where everything inside it wants to be seen and everything outside wants to be invisible. I have very little knowledge of how masking and alpha masking works but I think this is the method that i need to use for this project.
For context I was doing something similar to http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/ using pybox2d raycasting
This is what it looks like
[image]

I want everything in the shadow to not be able to be seen